# Facebook SDK Share Image with Text

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

Prior to using Facebook SDK we used to share via UIActivityViewController since Facebook does not allow for us to pre-fill information on the user sharing, our solution was to use information the user description of the Image being share `UIPasteboard.general.string`. So the app would switch to the messenger and the user could paste. This worked just fine until we started using the Facebook SDK.

Now it seems that the `UIPasteboard.general.string` is reset when it opens up messenger and we no longer can get the image description copied to the clipboard.

This is how I'm sharing to messenger:

```
let sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
sharePhoto.image = image

let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [sharePhoto]

FBSDKMessageDialog.show(with: content, delegate: delegate)
```

Comment: So you put this into the clipboard for the user already? That is not even allowed, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill _“Your app can suggest content, but the person using your app should choose to manually copy and paste or type that content themselves.”_

Comment: Yes I put it on the user clipboard but informing the user first, if they wanna copy it to the clipboard or not. But even if the user copies something from a UITextView, it just gets erased when the Facebook SDK opens up messenger.

Comment: Sounds like something Facebook might have implemented deliberately.

Comment: Check this, it is going to change it's api - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm stacked on that staff too after FB lib update. As for me - I figured out with web link on image like it shown below. As a result - you do not need ask user to paste something. You can do it by yourself and paste it to title or description.

```
let content = LinkShareContent(url: url,
                                       title: title,
                                       description: description,
                                       quote: nil,
                                       imageURL: imageURL)

        let dialog = ShareDialog(content: content)
        dialog.presentingViewController = parentVC
        dialog.mode = .automatic
        dialog.completion = { result in
             ...
        }

        try? dialog.show()
```

Comment: title and descriptions are read-only properties now. So, we can't provide text for title or description properties

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is not support UI share both image and text. If you want to share an image and a text together, you can create a custom story from your app's settings, and share it as an open graph story. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios).

Comment: It seems OpenGraph settings not available for facebook app in developer account. So, how do we configure open graph settings to avail those features?